# Node.js - MongooseJS schema error that I can’t figure out

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What is wrong with my schema?

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
        name:
                {
                        first : {type: String}
                    ,    last : {type : String}
                }
    ,    password: {type: String}
    ,    username: {type: String}
    , role: RoleSchema
  , created_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
  , modified_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
})

var RoleSchema = {
        type: [String]
    ,    study_type: [String]
}

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `role`
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The embedded Schema (Roles) needs to be above the UserSchema

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Roles schema having to be imported before the UserSchema.

In the newer versions of Mongoose, the following sort of syntax was also needed for to get beyond the `'TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path`:

```
var SomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema();

  SomeSchema.add({
    key1: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    key2: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    key3: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  });

  SomeSchema.get(function(val){
    // Remove the _id from the Violations
    delete val._id;
    return val;
  });
```

And the parent:

```
var ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    parentKey: String,
    someArray: [SomeSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema)
```

This happened when switching from Mongoose 3.x to 4.x.